# How to append strings to a string in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I do the below, I get an empty string for some reason.

```
var jsObj2 = {
  "key1": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"
};

var c = '';
for (var key in jsObj2) {
  c.concat(key + ': ' + jsObj2[key]);
}

console.log(c);
```

What I would have hoped for where

```
key1: value3
key4: value4
```

## Question

Can anyone explain why my attempt doesn't work, and how the NodeJS approach would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string `c` is not modified in place, but returns a new string.

Use `c = c.concat(key + ': ' + jsObj2[key]);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign concated value to a variable.

```js
var jsObj2 = {
  "key1": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"
};

var c = '';
for (var key in jsObj2) {
  c = c.concat(key + ': ' + jsObj2[key]);
}

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

prefer to use `+=` operator

```js
var jsObj2 = { key1: "value3"
             , key4: "value4"
             }
  , c      = ''
  , comma  = ''
  ;
for (var key in jsObj2)
  {
  c    += comma + key + ': ' + jsObj2[key]
  comma = ', '
  }
console.log(c)
```

or :

```js
var jsObj2 = { key1: "value3"
             , key4: "value4"
             }
  , c = Object.entries(jsObj2)
              .map(([k,v])=>`${k}: ${v}`)
              .join(', ')
  ;
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it:

```js
const jsObj2 = {"key1": "value3", "key4": "value4"};
let str = Object.entries(jsObj2).join('').replace(/,/g, ': ');
console.log(str);
```